# How to show log with filtering by author date?

Tags: git

I am working on a repository that was imported to git and all the committer dates are wrong (5years+ squashed to 2 days). I have read that by default git log `--since='...'` will filter using committer date, so the results are useless for me, my command looks like below:

```
$ git log --since='2011-09-21' --pretty=format:"%aD,%h,%s" --author='Zeo' myfile.cpp
```

is there a switch that will make `--since` use author date instead of committer date?

I have searched everywhere, but cant find it.

[edit]
To rewrite all authors dates into committer dates after such import use:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"'
```

from : https://gist.github.com/568898

Answer (score 3):

I found this from the git list dated back to 2009,

```
git log --format='%H %at' |
perl -ane '
BEGIN {
use DateTime::Format::Natural;
$max_age = DateTime::Format::Natural->new->parse_datetime(
"last friday"
)->epoch;
}
print $F[0], "\n" if $F[1] < $max_age;
'
```

Comment: thanks, I will stick to filtering by tags, thankfully they were being added daily in previous repository